# Having issues with Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpting

I'm currently attempting to sculpt onto a cube with a subdivision multiplier and when attempted I don't appear to get any results unless my brush is at max size but this distorts the entire object in undesirable ways.

I believe it has something to do with blender thinking I'm using a pen, when in fact I'm using a mouse so it isn't receiving pressure but i don't know how to change this setting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: You cant sculpt on top of modifiers, since sculpting only affects the base geometry. You need to apply the subdivision surface first (if i understand your question correctly).

Comment: Okay I haven't applied it. I had it sitting in the menu so i could edit it when necessary

Comment: So do you still have an issue if you apply it?